# Parent-child insert deadlocking in Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, azure

We frequently use the following form of a Table per Type inheritance hierarchy in our data model:

```
TABLE [Base] (
 [Id] uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY),
 ...base columns
)
TABLE [DerivedA] (
 [Id] uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY,
 CONSTRAINT [FK_DerivedA_Base] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [Base] ([Id]),
 ...extended columns
)
```

The process for inserting entities of type DerivedA is therefore to insert a row into Base followed by a row into DerivedA, using the same primary key.

The issue is that this pattern leads to deadlocks on concurrent inserts. The mechanism of the deadlock is well explained by
[Steve Howard](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/articles/1681):

1. Process A inserts a row in Base, acquiring an IX lock on its page.
2. Process B inserts a row in Base, acquiring an IX lock on the same page.
3. Process A inserts a row in DerivedA. The foreign key check requests an S lock on the page which conflicts with the IX lock held by B.
4. Process B inserts a row in DerivedB. The foreign key check requests an S lock on the page which conflicts with the IX lock held by A.
5. Each process waits on the other to proceed, and thus they are deadlocked.

Note that, as Howard points out, the issue cannot be resolved by using snapshot transactions, since the foreign key constraint check is performed by the engine using a Read Committed isolation level.

However, I cannot implement the solution offered by Howard--namely, disabling page locking on the Base clustered index--because page locking cannot be disabled in Azure SQL. Note also that the uniqueidentifiers we use are generated such that the two rows going into Base are likely to end up on the same page if they are inserted nearly simultaneously, and so the likelihood of deadlocking is very high. This insert operation is the most frequent write triggered by our users and so eliminating the deadlocking (rather than, say, retrying after the deadlock) while maintaining concurrency is important.

Suggestions for how to proceed?

Comment: Can you serialize the inserts via a queue? It may or may not be practical depending on your specific problem domain.

Comment: Let's say that it's an option but not a cheap one--all else being equal, it would be better not to have to abandon concurrent inserts altogether.